# It is possible to write function in Kotlin (ie. at top level). Can I unit-test those at top-level too?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, kotlin

If I write code at top level (outside of a class).

Can I write JUnit test of this code without creating a class for this testing purpose?

Comment: Of course - just have your test case call the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a top level function in a file:

```
// functions.kt
package some.pack.age

fun add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
```

You can create a test for it like so (an easy way to create this file in IntelliJ is to use the `Alt + Enter` shortcut on the function's name, and choose `Create test`):

```
// FunctionKtTest.kt - the default suggested name
package some.pack.age

import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Test

class FunctionsKtTest {
    @Test
    fun additionIsCorrect() {
        assertEquals(5, add(2, 3))
    }
}
```

The JUnit test itself does require a class to be defined that holds the `@Test` functions, of course you can name this class anything you want.

If you place this class in the same package as the function, you don't even have to import it. If you were to place it in another package, you could still import your top level function like so:

```
import some.pack.age.add
```

Comment: The problem is not so much that JUnit requires a class because top-level functions are implictly placed in a class called after the file name. The problem is that top-level functions are static and JUnit requires `@Test` functions to be non-static.

Comment: if two top level function is in one class, it is good to write tests for both in one test class? or separate tests of each function to a class?

Comment: @David: Completely up to you, as there's no functional difference.